# Error message that UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have an app which uses a `UISearchBar` to dynamically search from an external API based on user input.

The app is searching the external API fine and displaying results correctly, but when I  select any row from the search results, the screen freezes and I am getting this error;

> Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread
>   UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread

I have absolutely no idea how I can fix this.

Here is the code;

```
- (void) run: (id) param  {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [self URL]];
    [parser setDelegate: self];
    [parser parse];
    [parser release];
    [delegate parseDidComplete];
    [pool release];
} 

- (void) parseXMLFile: (NSURL *) url
{ 
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [self setURL: url];
    NSThread* myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                 selector:@selector(run
   object: nil];
    [myThread start];
    [pool release];
}
```

Comment: How do you fetch the API data? Looks like you do that asynchronously in another thread. UIKit is not threadsafe, so UI stuff must always be done in the main thread. Can you give us some relevant code?

Comment: Here is the code;
- (void) run: (id) param  {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [self URL]];
    [parser setDelegate: self];
[parser parse];
[delegate parseDidComplete];
} 
- (void) parseXMLFile: (NSURL *) url
{ 
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [self setURL: url];
NSThread* myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                 selector:@selector(run
   object: nil];
    [myThread start];
}

Comment: I am using thread so that the screen does not freeze while the external API is accessed. So is there any way by which i can do that as well as solve the UIKit thread issue ??

BTW, I do not understand what exactly does that issue mean (UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread)

Comment: Is it absolutely essential for me to use NSOperation and NSOperationQueue, as I'll have to learn that from scratch?

Can it be done without using these.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> "Tried to obtain the web lock from a
>   thread other than the main thread or
>   the web thread UIKit should not be
>   called from a secondary thread"

The fix is conceptually simple; don't update the UI from your thread.

Assuming the `parseDidComplete` is where the message is sourced, then something like this will "work":

```
[delegate performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(parseDidComplete) withObject: nil waitUntilDone: YES];
```

"Work" because threading is hard and this answer completely ignores any synchronization issues you might have.

Note that you'd be better off using `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`.  They are well documented and there are a bunch of examples.

Comment: I do not know NSOperation and NSOperationQueue. Could you provide any similar example for NSOperation or NSOperationQueue which I can use as reference.

Comment: Read the documentation;  it provides more information and better examples than I could type into SO.

Comment: @bbum what's the advantage of using NSOperation and Queue IF you've already implemented using `performSelectorOnMainThread`? If you wrote a blog article about this, I'd read it ;) Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect the line:

```
[delegate parseDidComplete];
```

If the delegate class is interacting with UIKit components, then the background thread that is retrieved the XML contents is then calling the front-end objects which must all be in the main thread.

You may want to look at using an NSOperation and NSOperationQueue to do the asynchronous operations.  I believe that provides a more threadsafe way to handle this type of use case.

Comment: you are correct.  You may want to add that to your answer above.