# Problem with Threading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, nsthread

I am getting following error when i tried to make a thread for an image uploading and parsing..

> **error**
>
> Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

I have tested this method with other simple statements but when i tried to access content from web this error arises...

Can any one tell me how to solve this problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672254/uikit-should-not-be-called-from-a-secondary-thread)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been coming up often recently, including quite a few times on SO.

Here is one:

[Error message that UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672254/uikit-should-not-be-called-from-a-secondary-thread)

Answer (score 2):

You are probably accessing some of the UIKit objects (adding/removing subviews, changing text etc.) from the secondary thread. If you do need to do that, then use performSelectorOnMainThread

Comment: Max is right you can update/change UI Control's only from Main thread. use performSelectorOnMainThread for this purpose.