# How to upload a file in background while iPhone app is doing something else

Tags: objective-c

Just want to find out, in Xcode, how to set 2 threads running?
E.g. upload file (size is large like 3-4 MB) to website
and it allows the user to proceed on using the app without having this upload file to prevent him to doing other things.

I know that I can show the network activity icon on the top bar but not sure how to separate the thread.

```
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you use for networking [NSURLConnection](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/350-How-to-make-asynchronous-HTTP-requests-with-NSURLConnection) or other framework like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#creating_an_asynchronous_request) simply use asynchronous request type. It will be running in the background and your app will not be effected, all other tasks will be running on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) or [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) they both have upload file examples   .

Comment: what about if I use void dispatch_async(
   dispatch_queue_t queue,
   dispatch_block_t block);

Comment: You can use [GCD API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) but for a task that you mentioned in your question using NSOperation would be more appropriate. You can find more info about Concurrency Programming [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091)

Comment: I encounter error "void _WebThreadLockFromAnyThread(bool), 0x2f45b0: Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread." while I use the code 
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:kMAINSTORYBOARD bundle: nil];
UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: kMAINNAVIGATION];
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

Comment: From code you provided I can't tell what could cause the problem, but error description is pretty clear - you shouldn't update your UI from the background thread. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672254/uikit-should-not-be-called-from-a-secondary-thread) the similar question/answer

Comment: Is there a way to update the UI (like navigate to another ViewController) while upload happens in the another thread? I still don't know why this error happens when my upload is within the dispatch_async()

Comment: Can you please edit your main question providing that dispatch_async code block?